# Maximum absolute voltage deviation at the output (with systematic imperfections)

Tags: input-bias-current

The opamp here is ideal except for the bias currents. In order to calculate the maximum absolute voltage deviation at the output, I was thinking of sum the deviation of Vos and deviation of current, being that the deviation of current, for the maximum is R2*Ib (I think.)

My problem is for the deviation of Vos because in the exercise description, they give Ios (so I did the Ohm laws to get Vos) and then calculate the deviation for Vos with gain*Vos, but then I got the wrong answer in the end. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Show your calculations please.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](/Users/patriciavieira/Downloads/IMG_0534.jpg)

Comment: Ib(+)=7.5e-9 + (1/2)(1.4e-9)=8.2e-9
gain=R2(c*R1=248.28e6
-Current deviation:
Vo(Ib)=R2*Ib(+)=5.33e-5
-Voltage deviation:
Vo(Vos)=gain*(Ios*R2)=2.25e12

-Maximum absolute voltage deviation=2.25e12 V( which is very wrong)

Comment: You need to put it in your question and, if possible, format it using latex. Eg \$I_{b+} = 7.5\text{ nA}+\dfrac{1.4\text{ nA}}{2}\$ is written like this: `\$I_{b+} = 7.5\text{ nA}+\dfrac{1.4\text{ nA}}{2}\$`